# How to get_range for available rows in Cassandra?

Tags: cassandra, pycassa

In my application, I want to get all the rows in a column family, but to ignore the rows that are temporarily unavailable (e.g. some nodes are down).

I have multiple nodes. If one of the node is down, then `get_range` will throw `UnavailableException`, and I can get nothing.

What I want is to get all the rows that are currently available, because, to the user, its better than nothing. How can I do this?

- I'm using pycassa.
- The row keys in my column family are like random string, so I cannot use `get` to get all the rows one by one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If [`get_range` by token support](https://github.com/pycassa/pycassa/issues/170) is added to pycassa, you could fetch each token range (as reported by `describe_ring`) separately, discarding those that resulted in an UnavailableException.  Barring that, using consistency level ONE is your best option, as Dean mentions.

Comment: Thank you. If this feature is added, the problem can be totally solved. In my case, I found that I mistakenly used replication factor 1, which is one of the causes of the my problem.

Comment: Token support has been added to get_range() in pycassa 1.9.1.

Answer (score 0):

there should be a call to get that takes a List of rowkeys so you don't need to get them one by one.  Also, if you have an index, that can help.  for instance playORM has an index for each partition of a table(and you can have as many partitions as you want).  With that, you can then iterate over each index and call get passing it a LIST of keys.

Also, make sure your consistency read is set to ONE as well ;).

later,
Dean

Comment: Thank you for your help. But in my case, the row keys are like random string, so I don't know what row keys are there in the column family before I get the response of get_range(). Thus I can't pass a list of keys to get().

Comment: I am assuming you are using Ordered partitioner?  IF you had an index, you WOULD have the row keys, and ifyou table is too big for one index you could have multiple indice rows so you "could" get the row keys and issue them all to a get or multiple gets may better if you want to batch each up.